# plantuml: how to draw 2 sequence messages on same level?

Tags: uml, plantuml

I have some code like this:

```cpp
class A
{
    void update()
    {
        update1();
        update2();
    }
}
```

and I'd like to draw it in plantuml.

I tried something like this:

```
@@startuml
autoactivate on
A -> A : update
A -> A : update1
return
A -> A : update2
return
@@enduml
```

then I got uml diagram like this:

[image: plantuml]

I don't like the dotted lines (return message). but if I remove the return message, the message levels (hierarchy) will be messed up.
they are not on the same level any more.

```
@@startuml
autoactivate on
A -> A : update
A -> A : update1
A -> A : update2
@@enduml
```

is like this: [image: update1 & update 2 not on same level]

I want `update1` and `update2` to be on the same level.

Comment: They are at the same level, aren't they?

Comment: Your diagram absolutely matches the code. You could leave away the dotted retrun message to make it implicit (but I have no idea about PlantUML). However, the representation is correct that way.

Comment: @muszeo I attached another diagram without the return message. They are not on the same level.

Comment: just do not use _autoactivate on_, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *autoactivate on* the *return* are mandatory

---

Doing :

```
@@startuml
A -> A : update
activate A
A -> A : update1
activate A
deactivate A
A -> A : update2
activate A
deactivate A
return
@@enduml
```

the result is :

[image]

or replacing the last *return* by *deactivate* :

```
@@startuml
A -> A : update
activate A
A -> A : update1
activate A
deactivate A
A -> A : update2
activate A
deactivate A
deactivate A
@@enduml
```

[image]

---

Of course an other way is to use a UML modeler rather than a drawer

Comment: This is the first time I use plantuml, I just looked at the examples to find the ways